# Python 3.8: @typing.overload usage with typing.Literal and Enum values

Tags: python, enums, overloading, literals, typing

According to https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time

typing.Literal works with Enum values as legal parameters.
But autocomplete does not work with following code:

```
import typing
from enum import Enum


class A:
    a: int


class B:
    b: int


class C(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2


@typing.overload
def get(v: typing.Literal[C.A]) -> A: ...


@typing.overload
def get(v: typing.Literal[C.B]) -> B: ...


def get(v) -> typing.Union[A, B]:
    pass


a = get(C.A)  # <- autocomplete returns instance of A, fine
b = get(C.B)  # <- autocomplete returns instance of A as well
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the problem in @overload with Enum values as argument?

In exchange, works totally fine with 'int' parameters, like

```
import typing
from enum import Enum


class A:
    a: int


class B:
    b: int


@typing.overload
def get_int(v: typing.Literal[0]) -> A: ...


@typing.overload
def get_int(v: typing.Literal[1]) -> B: ...


def get_int(v) -> typing.Union[A, B]:
    pass


a = get_int(0)   # <- autocomplete returns A
b = get_int(1)   # <- autocomplete returns B
```

Comment: Inference of this works fine with MyPy. For *which tool* does autocomplete not work?

Comment: I'm using pycharm and this seems to be the problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54989/PyCharm-does-not-take-an-enum-into-account-when-using-typing.Literal-and-typing.overload-and-typehints-the-default-case-instead